# How to install Beta version of Flash?

Tags: 11.10, flash

I have tried to install the Beta version of Flash using the Firefox plugin Flash-Aid with no luck. The Beta version right now is the 11.2 and I wanted to test it how it changed in performance wise but I seen to find it difficult to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, uninstall any Flash version on your system. Download the suitable (32bit or 64bit) installer here:
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer11-2.html

Extract the archive and put libflashplayer.so file in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins for system wide:

```
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```

For user only:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins # If there is not
cp libflashplayer.so ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Comment: Somehow is not working. Firefox, even after rebooting still reads 11.0.1.152

Comment: Ok, I tried it myself. Unfortunately, /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin directory for system wide solution does not work for me. Instead, /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins works. Also ~/.mozilla/plugins is also working here. So, first uninstall flashplugin-downloader and flashplugin-installer packages, close Firefox and just copy the file to ~/.mozilla/plugins directory. You can check via about:plugins. But, it is not stable. For example on Youtube I see just mixed colours. On dailymotion and a few other sites it is working though.

Comment: Follow your comment and yes it worked. The actual Beta usage was for performance and testing and as you say, it is very unstable, crashes a lot and has several bugs because still in Beta. Tested in several sites as you did. The overall performance is almost the same as 11.0. Thanks again heartsmagic.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, I fixed the wrong directory name for system wide Flash in my answer.